# How to simulate events from Openlayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, events, trigger, unit-testing

I am working on a GIS API that uses OpenLayers. I am testing it using QUnit.

The problem is I need to simulate clicks and trigger some events to be able to test the whole code.

For example, I have a feature to draw a polygon and I want to just trigger the "featureadded" event. Is it possible to trigger OpenLayers events without actually working graphically?

Thanks